# DLL Entry Point Not Located

Tags: dll

Had to do a PC refresh Windows 8.1 64x after some problems with Windows Installer as new softwares couldn't be loaded. Problem was partially solved for most programs except for a few were the error messages are shown in the pictures.

Error Messages:

**the entry point procedure _ltoa could not be located in the dynamic link library Qt5Qml.dll**

**the entry point procedure realloc could not be located in the dynamic link library firefox.exe**

**the entry point procedure _callnewh could not be located in the dynamic link library wxbase313u_xml_vc_custom.dll**

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqNFi.png) [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBoq6.png) [Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeW2X.png)

All available solutions were tested: un/reinstall the programs, cmd regsvr, All In One Runtime. The only thing left now is to go for a DLL editor. Any suggestions?